# CMD Don't let user control the computer

Tags: windows, cmd, background, controls

I am making a batch logon system and was wondering if it was possible to deny access to a computer if the login system wasn't completed.
So E.G.
deny access on startup
make background of computer black
username: admin
password: admin
allow access to computer

If you need to try and make it clear please comment :)

Comment: You know Windows already *has* a logon system, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows requires you to login unless you enable automatic login.

To disable auto login (for windows 7 at least):

- Press windows key.
- Type `netplwiz`
- On the user tab untick `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer`

Then users will have to use the login system.